# QML import and Java determination errors and warnings when building by the Arm7 kit

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I installed a great bunch of SDK packages

[image]

and went for building the *APK* file of a QML application using the **Build** button for the *Arm7* kit on Qt Creator 4.8.0 on my Windows machine.

There're, unfortunately, a number or errors and warnings which are quite astonishing for me because everything is seemingly proper.

Here's my Devices:

[image]

When building, I got the following errors and warnings in red:

```
*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.*
*What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.*

*Get more help at https://help.gradle.org*

*Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Fusion.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Imagine.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
Building the android package failed!
-- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
23:23:03: The process "C:\Qt\5.12.0\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.*
*Error while building/deploying project Ping_Pong (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (Clang Qt 5.12.0 for Android ARMv7))
When executing step "Build Android APK"**
```

The errors and warnings pertain to *JDK* and *QtQuick.Controls* apparently.
Jdk is the updated version and here is the controls I used in `mani.qml` for instance:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
```

What is the problem, why still do I get these errors, please?

Comment: Try JDK version 8 instead of version 11.

Comment: Do you mean "jdk-8u191-windows-x64" (207 MB) please? I'm using Qt 5.12

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Qt is picky about the version, older don't work, newer don't work.

Comment: As for the warnings, those seem to be "normal" - I've been getting them for years, but the apps seem to work fine. If you examine the output from a Qt application running on android, there is whole great wall of errors and warnings before the app gets running...

Comment: I used that jdk and went for rebuilding the app. Now many more [errors!](https://codeshare.io/5D6Lkr) :(

Comment: There's a linking error with SDK. And I suppose it's because I'm using an old version of SDK. I installed a file called "installer_r24.4.1-windows" to give me SDK tools because I wanted to use it to manage packages instead of Android Studio. I thought if I re-install Android Studio and it gives me SDK which is part of it, the linking issue will be solved. But the problem is whatever I install Android Studio no SDK folder will be installed this time!